# time larger than fixed in cplex routines

Tags: c, cplex

i have this in the main :

```
#define N 23

start-time=clock();

     readData(c); // just read a matrix of integer size N (in this case matrix 23*23) 
     lp (c,d);   // resolve it by cplex with a time limit cplex command  1h 30

final-time=clock();
 time = (final_time -start-time) *0.001;

 printf("\n CPU = %f sec\n\n", time);
```

the problem shows:

```
Default row names c1, c2 ... being created.
solution status is Feasible
obj. value: 5557
gap : 1.1697

 CPU = 10800.494141 sec
```

why the time is so large? did the main() spend another 1 h just to read a matrix size 23*23 !!!!!!

Comment: You have *start-time* a couple of places and *final-time* as well.  Those are not variable names in C, they're an expression ( final minus time ).  If that's from your code, I'd be surprised it compiled, let alone work.  You probably meant underscores instead of those minus signs, but let us know.

Comment: thanks for the remark but i have just changed the name before asking my question to be signifiant for who read this question .in my code i use other variable name for time.

Answer (score 1):

[clock](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/clock.3.html)

> The value returned is the CPU time used so far as a clock_t; **to get
>   the number of seconds used, divide by CLOCKS_PER_SEC**

Comment: thanks.is it false to metion final time and start time as integer and do (final-start)*0.001 to get the value in second?

Comment: you can subtract. But the time is measured in clock ticks In order to get in seconds you must divide it by `CLOCKS_PER_SEC`. Multiplying it by `0.001` brings you nowhere in this context